# Thingsboard - RPC - Knob - Request Timeout

Tags: request, widget, timeout, rpc, thingsboard

I've been trying to get the Knob Widget to send data to a temperature meter in my Thingsboard Dashboard but all i get is "Request Timeout" and no data to the temperature meter. Is there someone who have succeeded with this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with this before. Find more infos in the documentation:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/rpc-request-tutorial/

You have to prepare the device in order to subscribe to the RPC messages from the ThingsBoard Server (e.g. via MQTT):
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/#processing-server-side-rpc-on-the-device

This could be missing in your case, resulting with "Request Timeout.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at those two sites.